# Download and share file in 2022 (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, clean-architecture

I see so many outdated approaches on how to download and share files in Java but couldn't seem to find any good approach on Kotlin.
There are just so many different ways and somehow most of them are not working properly.

I'm using MVVM + Clean Architecture and I simply want to download a file (mp3) from URL and share it with WhatsApp.

Here is what I found so far for Kotlin (just the download part):

```
override suspend fun downloadSound(soundURL: String) {

    val storage = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        URL(soundURL).openStream().use { input ->
            FileOutputStream(File(storage.absolutePath, "shareFile.mp3")).use { output ->
                input.copyTo(output)
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

This used to work fine but out of a sudden I'm getting an error on Android 11+:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/shareFile.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

On Android 10 I eliminated this problem with adding:

```
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

to my Manifest.

Here is how I share the sound after downloading:

```
try {
    val storage =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    val file = File(storage.absolutePath, "shareFile.mp3")
    if (file.exists()) {
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
            file
        )
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri) 
        intent.type = "audio/mp3"
        context.startActivity(
            Intent.createChooser(
                intent,
                "Share via"
            )
        )
    }
} catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    Log.i("MeisterTag", "FILE DOES NOT EXIST")
}
```

I'm also not sure what permissions I need to request, if any.
For now I requested:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

What is the most up-to-date approach that is working for API 23+

Comment: You ask for two problems in your post . Confusing. Please concentrate on the downloading first. Remove the share stuff as you confused me with all those problems.

Comment: @blackapps the question is simple, "how to download and share a file in Kotlin (2022)".
You can ignore my code, I just need someone who describes a good and working approach

Comment: "This used to work fine but out of a sudden I'm getting an error on Android 11+" -- there is already a file by that name in the `Downloads/` directory, put there by something other than your current installed app. Consider downloading elsewhere, such as `getCacheDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()` on `Context`.